# Read button from bluetooth low energy remote control with an Arduino Nano 33

Tags: arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, remote-control

I am try to read the buttons of a simple Bluetooth low energy remote control (Volume, Page). For the first i tried to read "Increase Volume" but had no success.

What I have done so far:

1. Scan the BLE (ArduinoBLE-->Central-->Scan). Works fine and gets lots of Data.
2. Push different Buttons during the scans (Point 1) an compare whether a bit switches --> nothing.
3. Test with Smartphone. Press "Increase Volume" Button --> ok, works fine.
4. Try to sniff the data --> could not find the "button bits".

I think my error is, that I have to send a "Read request" or something else. I am new to Bluetooth and don't know how.

Would be glad if there is an example code for doing this.

Comment: It's still not clear what you are trying to do. When you say "Push different buttons during scans" - are you pushing them in the Arduino Nano 33? If this is the case, what bit switches are you expecting to see? And what do you mean that it works fine on Android volume button?

Comment: These are the hardware buttons on the remote control. I push them with my finger during scanning BLE :-) . I was expecting to see some bits changing during the Scan.

Comment: "Android volume button" means, that when pushing the hardware Button "increase Volume" on the remote control the Arduino Smartphone increases Volume. So this information is send, but I cant get it with the Arduino Nano..

Answer (score 0):

OK I think I understand your question now. It seems that you are trying to see if advertisement data changed based on the button switch from the remote control. While this is very application/product dependant, most BLE communication and data exchange happens over a **connection**. In other words, you need to connect from your ArduinoBLE to the BLE remote control.So your steps are:-

1. Scan from Arduino Nano 33.
2. Once the BLE remote controller is found, connect to it.
3. Once you are connected to the BLE remote controller, read data to see when button switches happen.

Unfortunately, connecting to the BLE remote controller is the easy part, and the difficult part is reading the BLE data. In BLE, data exchange happens over GATT which is a unique thing to Bluetooth (it works in a similar fashion to client-server communication, where the remote will be a GATT server hosting data and the Nano 33 will be a GATT client reading the data from the server). Besides the complexity of the GATT communication, not all vendors expose how their data is represented in the GATT communication. In other words, if your remote control vendor does not expose how the button presses are exposed over GATT, it might be very difficult to find what you're looking for.

In any case, I've added a few links below to help you start on your journey:-

- [Getting started with BLE](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/getting-started-with/9781491900550/ch01.html)
- [Bluetooth Low Energy: A Primer](https://interrupt.memfault.com/blog/bluetooth-low-energy-a-primer)
- [Bluetooth framework and BLE GATT](https://www.btframework.com/gatt.htm)
- [Introduction to BLE: GATT](https://learn.adafruit.com/introduction-to-bluetooth-low-energy/gatt)
- [Connecting Nano 33 BLE Devices](https://docs.arduino.cc/tutorials/nano-33-ble-sense/ble-device-to-device)

Comment: Thanks, I digged into that. But I really don't want to be a BLE-expert :-)  .
I just want to read buttons from a simple remote control. I could strip it down via Wireshark to:
Service UUID: 0x1812
UUID report: 0x2a4d
Handle: 0x0032
Below that this value represent to 90 % the buttons.

I have testet several librarys, snippest, set in numbers from Wireshark... 

Frustrating. I could connect to the remote control via Arduino Nano and read out values, but not this "button-bits".

Maybe some BLE-expert has some code for that - please no more docu.